# ASP.NET Core Razor Pages - Get List Data to Display on Chart.js Graph

Tags: javascript, c#, chart.js, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a list (lstObjects) that is populated and am trying to get that data to display on my Chartist.js graph. When i hover my lstObjects in debug mode I can see the count of my list and the Object Type.

**In my `<script>` tags i currently have:**

```
    var chartOptions = {
    showLines: true,
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    legend: {
        display: false
    },
        tooltips: {
        displayColors: false
    },
    scales: {

        xAxes: [{
            display: true,
            ticks: {
                fontColor: 'black',
                padding: 20

            },
            gridLines: {
                borderDash: [1, 5],
                tickMarkLength: 0,
                zeroLineBorderDash: [1, 5],
                drawBorder: false,
                padding: 5
            }
        }],
        yAxes: [{
            display: true,
            ticks: {
                fontColor: 'black',
                padding: 20
            },
            gridLines: {
                color: 'rgba(85, 85, 85, 0.5)',
                borderDash: [1, 5],
                tickMarkLength: 0,
                zeroLineBorderDash: [1, 5],
                drawBorder: false,
                padding: 5
            }
        }]
    }
};

// Total Transactions Chart
var achChart = new Chart(document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d'), {
    // The type of chart we want to create
    type: 'line',

    // The data for our dataset
    data: {
        labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct'],
        datasets: [{
            label: '',
            lineTension: 0,
            fill: false,
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(25, 255, 102)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(25, 255, 102, 0.4)',
            borderWidth: 5,
            data: [0, 600, 200, 450, 800, 900, 550, 700, 800, 600]

        }]
    },
    options: chartOptions,

});
```

**I want the data the data to do something like this:**

```
 labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
 data: [100, 120, 180, 200, 300, 155, 220, 430, 275, 350, 120, 450]
```

I know I need to convert the list item into a string and have tried joining my SubmitDate but I can't get it working.

`var submitDate = string.Join("','", @Model.lstObjects.Select(x => x.RecordMonth).ToList());`

Does anyone have any recommendations on how I can get this accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this working using the `@Html.Raw` and `String.Join` on the commas. I also added ticks to surround the Month string like `'Jan'`.

Below is a sample of what I did.

```
data: {
      labels: [@Html.Raw("'" + String.Join("','", (Model.lstObjects.Select(x => x.RecordMonth).ToList())) + "'")],
```